# Remove attributes in request JMETER

Tags: java, jmeter, preprocessor, jsr223

In my test using JMeter some attributes are created, see bellow:

-----------------------------7d159c1302d0y0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="age"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit


I want to remove attributes:
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit


I try run below script but it didn't  worked.

```
def oldBody = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue()
def newBody = oldBody.replaceAll('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1','')
sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('',newBody,'')
```

Someone can help me please?

Comment: Did you tried `sampler.getHeaderManager().removeHeaderNamed("Content-Type");`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to amend the request from the HTTP Request sampler with `Use multipart form/data` box ticked **unfortunately it is not very possible** because [certain JMeter developers](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blame/98e8022b224c4b418ab3a9844e68d6ca23551ec4/src/protocol/http/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPHC4Impl.java#L1471) have their own interpretation of "optional" and "may" statements of the [RFC 2388 Section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388#section-3)

The options are in:

1. Switch to [HTTP Raw Request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-http-raw-request-sampler-when-and-how-to-use-it/) sampler which gives you full control of the request body/headers/etc on [TCP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Transmission_Control_Protocol_(TCP)) protocol level
2. Build your multipart form/data request manually using [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and HTTP Request sampler as it's described in [Testing REST API File Uploads in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter/) article